# How do I make Instagram OAuth (or any OAuth) always force the user to sign in, even if they are signed into the application's website?

Tags: node.js, express, oauth, instagram

I'm building a tool where a user would want to authenticate multiple Instagram accounts into the application. The problem I run into is if the user has already authenticated one and I initiate the OAuth dialogue again, the OAuth assumes that I want the access token of the user already logged in.

I have an iOS app that is similar and the way to avoid this is clear all the cookies of the Safari browser.

I'm using the `instagram-node` module right now.

```
app.get('/authenticateInstagram', function(req, res) {
    res.redirect(ig.get_authorization_url(redirectURI, {
        scope: ['basic', 'public_content', 'likes', 'follower_list', 'relationships'],
        state: 'a state'
    }));
});

app.get('/handleInstagramAuth', function(req, res) {
    ig.authorize_user(req.query.code, redirectURI, function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err.body);
            res.send('Didn\'t work');
        } else {
            console.log('Yay! Access token is ' + result.access_token);
            res.send('You made it!!');
        }
    });
});
```

So when I try to add another IG account (now that I've signed into an Instagram account already), I don't get prompted to log in by the OAuth sequence. It assumes I'm the previously signed in user.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of the following approaches

1. You can make a request to logout end point if Instagram supports it. Once you logout you can login again
2. I am not sure if instagram supports `prompt=login` parameter. If so it should take you to login page for each call.
3. I checked Instagram documentation and I think you can use Client side (Implicit) flow to login every time to get access token.